# Sobrescribir funcion .selectSingleNode en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

Necesito sobrescribir la función .selectSingleNode() de javascript que busca elementos dentro de una colección.
La quiero sobrescribir ya que mi aplicación la usa cientos de veces y es propia de IE.

Entiendo que normalmente se vuelve a definir la función.
Pero en este caso lo he hecho y no funciona.

```js
function init() {
  var xmlBank = getLoadXMLDoc(value);
  var dataBank = xmlBank.selectSingleNode("data");
}

function getLoadXMLDoc(xmlStr) {
    // Modern Browsers.
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "application/xml");
    } else {
        // Internet Explorer.
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "");
        xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
    }
    return xmlDoc
}


function selectSingleNode(xmlDoc, elementPath) {
    console.log("SelectSingleNode");
    if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        var nodes = document.evaluate(elementPath, xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
        var results = nodes.iterateNext();
        return results;
    } 
}
```

Por ejemplo, aquí, quisiera que entrara a la función que definí y no a la nativa.

Entiendo que no entra porque no se está sobrescribiendo dentro del objeto. Pero no sé como hacerlo.

Agradecería que alguien me pudiera ayudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me adelanté un poco a preguntar, pero dejo la forma en que funciona, por si a alguien le sirve:

```js
XMLDocument.prototype.selectSingleNode = function (xmlDoc, elementPath) {
    console.log("Interceptado");
}
```

De esta forma se puede sobrescribir.